# Engine Service Light - Erratic Idling 2007 Toyota Matrix

Tags: toyota, matrix

My 2007 Matrix idles between 1000 and 2,500 rpm and while driving there are times when the engine "stutters" almost like it's missing a plug... I checked the coolant level while the engine was cold and the level was exactly on the LOW mark...

Also the temperature gauge needle goes up and down...

Any ideas what maybe the problem?

Thanks,

Steve.

Comment: Could be a vacuum leak or a problem with the electronic throttle have you had the codes for the check engine light pulled?

Comment: That year Toyota and Pontiac Vibe (same car) had issues with intake manifold gaskets. The gasket would swell up and blow out. Try inducing some propane from a torch used for sweating pipes together around the intake. If the RPM increases then there is defiantly a leak.

Comment: All of the items mentioned ( fuel / air mix, idle control) will absolutely set a code. If you are in the US many auto parts suppliers and repair shops will read the codes for free. Read the codes then post 'em here by editing your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips... I haven't had a chance to take the car to check the codes for the engine light. Just curious as to what would cause the car engine temperature gauge needle to fluctuate so quickly...